# Matplotlib crash with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I was currently setting up my PyCharm with an own Conda environment, which crashes when I use just a usual matplotlib plot with the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([5,7,2,3,12,0])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

If I change back the python interpreter to the base interpreter and not my own one, it works. Going through the Windows Event Viewer, I found this:

```
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000087f7
Faulting process ID: 0x3534
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7d177bb33133a
Faulting application path: C:\Users\-\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\-\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Library\bin\freetype.dll
```

Does someone know what that means or how to fix it? Really strange that it works with the normal base environment, but not with my own environment. What could I have done wrong? Already reinstalled Anaconda and created a new environment.

Comment: If I copy and paste die freetype.dll file from the base file in the right folder of my own environment, it works again. What could have caused this problem?

Comment: @user202729 I'm not entirely sure if this is a duplicate, I'm not familiar with this conda+matplotlib combination. Anyway, you can flag for yourself if you have the necessary expertise to evaluate the question. I retagged the question, the tag SMEs will know what to do.